# How to turn separate data in a file and turn each line into a list?

Tags: python, list

Using this code I can separate data on a line and put it into a list as well as separating each line and making separate lists out of them.

```
p=open('file.txt').readlines()
for line in p:
    line = line.strip('\n')
    s = line.split()
    print(s)
```

When I run this code I get this:

```
['Danielle', 'Jennings', '5', '6', '5']
['Fred', 'Armstrong', '0', '0', '2']
```

I want to create a variable for each of these lists e.g. value1= ['Danielle', 'Jennings', '5', '6', '5', '5.3', '6'] but I'm not sure how. I then want to use the 'zip' function to join each corresponding value in this list. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

UPDATE:
I have turned all of the file lines into one list. But, if I didn't want to add every part of the line to the list, how would I do this?
For example, I only want to add one of the numbers to the list and then sort it but I just get this.
    ['9', '1', '4', 'Daniel', 'Ant', 'Kent', 'Riser', 'Abby', 'James']
When instead I want something more like this:
    ['Daniel', 'Riser', '1'] ['Ant', 'James', 9] etc

Comment: Instead of `print(s)`, just append `s` to another list: `myList.append(s)`

Comment: How many values are you expecting? `value1`, `value2`, etc.

Comment: I'm expecting 5 values minimum @Peter Wood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('file.txt') as text:
    people = [line.strip().split() for line text]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
The best way probably would be to put them into a dict

p=open('file.txt').readlines()
value_dict = {}
for i,line in enumerate(p):
    line = line.strip('\n')
    s = line.split()
    value_dict["value{:02d}".format(i)] = s
    print(s)
```

It would also be possible to create local variables as you go, but I would advise against it. I think better to have everything in one place, in this case a dict.

Comment: You say the best way would be a dict, but isn't this just an ordered list? The values are referred to by index, so a list named 'values' would be more efficient.

Comment: Yes, but OP wants "value"+number. If this is not some upfront requirement though, than normal list would be good as well.